# SQL Error, unable to create table on a certain format

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, create-table

I am facing an error when creating a table  between the following two statement

```
CREATE TABLE SECTION (
cid     varchar(10)     not null,
sno     varchar(3)      not null,
primary key (cid, sno),
foreign key (cid) references COURSE (cid)
);

CREATE TABLE ROUND_RELEASE (
cid     varchar(10)     not null,
sno     varchar(3)      not null, 
rid     int         not null,
foreign key (cid) references SECTION (cid),
foreign key (sno) references SECTION (sno),
foreign key (rid) references ROUND   (rid)
);
```

> Error Code: 1822. Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'round_release_ibfk_2' in the referenced table 'section'

However, when I try to swap the primary key order in SECTION table, I am able to create both table without error

```
CREATE TABLE SECTION (
cid     varchar(10)     not null,
sno     varchar(3)      not null,
primary key (**sno, cid**),
foreign key (cid) references COURSE (cid)
);

CREATE TABLE ROUND_RELEASE (
cid     varchar(10)     not null,
sno     varchar(3)      not null, 
rid     int         not null,
foreign key (cid) references SECTION (cid),
foreign key (sno) references SECTION (sno),
foreign key (rid) references ROUND   (rid)
);
```

The follow code above works, and I only swap the attribute, from my knowledge, the order does not matter, thus I am quite puzzled by why is this occurring.

Any guidance on this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Based on the error message, I assume that you are using MySQL.

What you are seeing is a [documented behavior](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html):

> In the referenced table, there must be an index where the referenced columns are the *first* columns in the same order.

Let me pinpoint, however, that your code probably does not do what you really want. You probably should be creating a *compound* foreign key, that references the tuples of columns, rather than one foreign key per column:

```
create table round_release (
    cid varchar(10) not null,
    sno varchar(3)  not null, 
    rid int not null,
    foreign key (cid, sno) references section(cid, sno),
    foreign key (rid) references round(rid)
);
```

One last thing to note is that your `round_release` table has no primary key defined; this is not a good practice, and might hurt you in several ways in the future. So, do create a primary key for the table, either as a separate column (possibly auto-incremented), or as a combination of existing columns.

Comment: There isn't a table called round (as in foreign key (rid) references round(rid)) as far as I can see.

Comment: @P.Salmon: I can only imagine that the `round` table exists, but that OP did not show it. Otherwise the second script, that OP said is working fine, would error...